# How much faster can web-workers make my browser game?

Tags: web-worker

I am making a browser game, and am wondering what types of performance improvements I could expect from web workers.

Refactoring would not be an issue, my code is already set up with this in mind.

Some have said that using web workers has made their game have 10-100x better performance -> https://www.quora.com/Are-web-workers-useful-for-JavaScript-games

I would only instantiate a pool of 8 web workers because that is the most I imagine to be necessary with my computer's 8 cores. Any more than that and it would provide no performance boost (Or would it for some reason?).

Given a little overhead from web workers and assuming bottlenecks are evenly spread, (graphics is not a bottleneck) this would typically leave me to expect about 7x performance when using web workers.

Or would it be the case that having graphics and logic on different intervals but the same thread reduces your performance to the extent that adding in 7 more threads could lead to 10-100x performance boosts?

Maybe it is the case that web workers are just not right for this quick game interval (50 ticks per second). And even if they did work it would only bring me improvements totaling 2x?

It will take some work to Integrate web workers, what should I expect in the end?

Comment: Please let me know if this is too general.

Comment: Just like hyperthreading could improve performance without additional physical core, my guess will be the quora answerer situation involve some thread that are stalled (from I/O, network, etc). Instead of waiting this single stalled thread (which could be hundred times longer than the execution of a single task), the queued stack are run on other thread. Of course this means your improvement will vary wildly, you'll need to profile your code to find out the hotspots.